# Error on coredata viewcontrollers

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I have a Core Data stack in which there are two entities: 'Client' and 'Car'. Both are represented by tableViewControllers.

The first tableViewController fetches the list of clients and then once selected, the second displays a list of cars *that* client owns. Both are pushed onto a navigation controller. When I go 'back' from the second viewcontroller the program shows the firstviewcontroller successfully, waits a second or so then crashes. When I did a 'build and debug' the console gave this error:

```
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
```

I dont understand it. Where should I look to find the error?

EDIT:I have included some code below to see if it is due to bad memory handling... I have deleted all commented out methods and as well as those not used before error crops up.

This is my ClientListViewController...

```
@implementation ClientListViewController

@synthesize clientsArray;
@synthesize coreDataModel;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View lifecycle


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Set the title
    self.title=@"Clients";

    [self populateTable];
}

-(void)populateTable {

    [self setClientsArray:[coreDataModel retrieveClientList]];

}


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
    return YES;
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [clientsArray count];
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    Client *client = (Client *)[clientsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [client name];

    return cell;

    [client release];


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Create and push new view controller.
    ClientCarsViewController *clientCarsViewController = [[ClientCarsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ClientCarsViewController" bundle:nil];

    //Pass the CoreDataModel to the view controller
    clientCarsViewController.coreDataModel = coreDataModel;

    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller
    Client *client = (Client *)[clientsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    clientCarsViewController.client = client;

    // Push the new viewController
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:clientCarsViewController animated:YES];

    // Release the objects
    [clientCarsViewController release];
    [client release];

}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Memory management

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Relinquish ownership any cached data, images, etc. that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Relinquish ownership of anything that can be recreated in viewDidLoad or on demand.
    self.clientsArray = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {

    [clientsArray release];
    [coreDataModel release];
    [super dealloc];

}


@end
```

This is my ClientCarsViewController implementation...

```
@implementation ClientCarsViewController

@synthesize carsArray;
@synthesize coreDataModel;
@synthesize client;


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View lifecycle


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = client.name;

    // Get client's cars
    NSSet *cars = client.cars;

    // Import them into the carsArray
    [self setCarsArray: [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[cars allObjects]]];

    [cars release];

}

-(void)addCarToClient {

    [coreDataModel addCarToClient:(Client *)client];

}


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
    return YES;
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [carsArray count];

}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    Car *car = (Car *)[carsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [car carName];
    return cell;

    [car release];

}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.

}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Memory management

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Relinquish ownership any cached data, images, etc. that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Relinquish ownership of anything that can be recreated in viewDidLoad or on demand.
    self.carsArray = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {

    [self.client release];
    [self.coreDataModel release];
    [self.carsArray release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Comment: The error generally means that you are trying to access something that is not allocated or that has been deallocated. What do you in that second after which the app crashes? Don't you have any additional info on the error: line where it happens, etc?

Comment: I dont do anything, I hit 'back' wait a second or so, then it crashes and gives me that error. No further info. I can only assume I have released an object I shouldnt have by that point. Ill edit my post and paste some code to see if that helps...

Comment: For these kinds of errors, you can turn on NSZombieEnabled environment variable. That helps you identify which released object you're trying to reach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are releasing objects you don't own. Have o look at Objective-C [Memory Management Rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html).

For example, when you obtain an object `client` like this:

```
Client *client = (Client *)[clientsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

You don't own it and should not release it.

Comment: I have removed 3 instances of release as you have suggested. 2 in the first view controller and 1 in the second. At runtime, I can now select a client and go 'back' successfully. I can even choose another client. However, as soon as I click a client for the second time, I get the same error and it crashes. Is there another fault as well?

Comment: found the final error - I was releasing the NSSet as well, but didnt own it! Thanks again.